# Installing Homebrew - mac 10.7.5

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to install homebrew on my mac verison 10.7.5, error msg comes up: The requested URL returned error: 404 Error: Failed to download resource "openssl" Download failed: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DomT4/LibreMirror/master/Open    help! how do i fix?

Answer (score 0):

[Try update your brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/35670)

`brew update`

I have encountered the same issue on my mac (10.11 El Captian)
It's seems OpenSSL want to force users and package management softwares  to  update by removing their previous version.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Webb Lu on this one.

Try **brew update** a few times.  If this isn't working then try the command **brew doctor** to correct any errors.

If this fixes the issue, you may want to then run **brew upgrade** to upgrade anything that is out of date.  For some reason I had to reinstall Xcode last night to run the upgrade command.  Not sure what happened there, but it seemed to work for me.

I don't know if this is the solution for your issue, but I figured I'd throw my hat in the ring ha ha.

Best of luck!